# How to add payment description during stripe checkout

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I was wondering how to add the payment description at the stripe checkout session, so that when I export the payment details into an excel file at the stripe dashboard,  it will be easier for me to filter the payment data.
[image]

Code for stripe checkout session

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
include("conn_db.php");
$total_amount = $_POST["total-amount"];
$total_amount = (int)($total_amount  * 100);
$stripe = new Stripe\StripeClient("sk_test_51MBGiuHGbqwDRBAKP9yCcv2q4EltFvPh5UbpMCRCpn7PkS2diEAlKfoe4ZHsRJYLnHZt0qKExGlbb1UI962x70cn00mLE1tInW");
header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
    $store_query = "SELECT * FROM store WHERE store_id = (SELECT store_id FROM cart WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['user_id']} GROUP BY user_id)";
    $store_arr = $mysqli->query($store_query)->fetch_array();
    $store_id = $store_arr["store_id"];
    $store_name = $store_arr["store_name"];
    
    $query = "SELECT c.*, m.*, u.* FROM user u INNER JOIN cart c ON u.user_id = c.user_id INNER JOIN mitem m ON c.mitem_id = m.mitem_id WHERE c.user_id = {$_SESSION['user_id']} AND c.store_id = {$store_id};";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $line_items_array = [];
    
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        array_push(
            $line_items_array,
            [
                'price_data' => [
                    'product_data' => [
                        'name' => $row->mitem_name,
                        'description' => $store_name,
                        'metadata' => [
                            'pro_id' => $row->mitem_id
                        ]
                    ],
                    'unit_amount' => (int)($row->mitem_price  * 100),
                    'currency' => "myr",
                ],
                'quantity' => $row->cart_amount
            ]
        );
    }
    
    
    print_r($line_items_array);
    
    
    $session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
        "success_url" => ADD_URL . '?response=1&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        "cancel_url" => FAILED_URL,
        "payment_method_types" => ['card'],
        "mode" => 'payment',
        "line_items" => $line_items_array,
        
    ]);
    header("Location: " . $session->url);
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-description

```
...
"payment_method_types" => ['card'],
"mode" => 'payment',
"payment_intent_data" => ["description" => "My description of the payment"],
...
```